# running two vga

Tags: vga

I am running two VGA  as follows

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:a2600000-a261ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a2620000-a263ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0000000-a03fffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

my question is how to stop intel vga and use AMD drivers because my machine is making noice and heating always 
I am expecting the step by step answers because i am a new user

Comment: Are you running a laptop? What are these two VGAs, both are separate external monitors? What ports are you connecting them to?

Comment: both vga are running in a laptop

Comment: Are you saying you have two VGA ports on your laptop? each connecting to an external VGA monitor?

Comment: i dont know about that when i am running that command i am getting the above display